# Google Sheets Query for Maximum Date

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-query

I have a table which I would like to return in its entirety but filtered by column H with the maximum date as rows have duplicate account numbers with different dates.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x3hYy1igiL3_lqhFE3IwrQNFbOjdpXRtHLAbOXB2BE4/edit?usp=sharing

I'm using this query right now, but clearly I'm overlooking something, can anyone help, please?

```
=QUERY(B3:I12, "Select *, Max(H) WHERE B is not null Group by C")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final formula was `={DataTable;SORTN(SORT(Data,17,0),99^99,2,2,1)}`

DataTable is the headings and Data is the dataset. Out of 14,000 lines this filtered down to around 7,000 lines of unique rows with the highest (Maximum) date.

Answer (score 1):

correct syntax would be:

```
=QUERY(B3:I12, 
 "select B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,max(H)
  where B is not null
  group by B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I")
```

---

but you probably need this:

```
={B3:I3; SORTN(SORT(B4:I, 7, 0), 99^99, 2, 2, 1)}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I prefer the query but I tried this and found it didn't filter the max dates?

Comment: Could you explain what's going on here? ={B3:I3; SORTN(SORT(B4:I, 7, 0), 99^99, 2, 2, 1)}

Comment: when you use "group by" parameter in query you need to list all non-aggregating columns. so if you want to return full range B:I then B:I needs to also be under group by. - anyway, this could be applied in some cases but not in your scenario.

Comment: we construct table with { } array brackets where we copy headers B3:I3 and under it we construct our filtered table. first we SORT range B4:I based on 7th column in descending mode (thats the 0 after 7) then we use SORTN where we return all rows (thats the 99^99) then we use parameter 2 (which means "remove all duplicates") in column 2 (the 2nd 2) in acsending mode (the last value 1)

Comment: I have a much larger data set, 14,000 lines approx, so I assume this SORTN 99^99 parameter would not work for that?

Comment: it will. 99^99 = 3.697296e+197 lines - see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807758/how-many-digits-is-9999-without-a-calculator

Comment: or in simple terms... 99^99 = 369729637649726772657187905628805440595668764281741102430259972423552570455277523421410650010128232727940978889548326540119429996769494359451621570193644014418071060667659301384999779999159200499899 rows, so you are pretty much safe

Comment: I tried it but it returned more than 20,000 lines which is more than when I started?

Comment: I’ll try again tomorrow but thank you for your help and explanation

Comment: This worked, thank you, it was my data reference that was incorrect.